# Where can i find update.bsh file inside JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, runtime, beanshell

I am trying to use beanshell.server to update timer value at runtime .

source : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fQ_ZYf_ks24&list=PLJ9A48W0kpRIjLkZ32Do9yDZXnnm7_uj_&index=59&ab_channel=QAInsights-NaveenKumarNamachivayamQAInsights-NaveenKumarNamachivayamj
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onAAk.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to **create this file** and put it under "extras" folder of your JMeter installation, the contents of the file is somewhere at [1:50 timestamp in the video](https://youtu.be/fQ_ZYf_ks24?list=PLJ9A48W0kpRIjLkZ32Do9yDZXnnm7_uj_&t=110) and it's as simple as:

```
printprop("timer");
setprop("timer", args[0]);
```

[image]

More information:

- [Beanshell Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server)
- [How to Change JMeter´s Load During Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-change-jmeters-load-during-runtime)

Comment: Have created update.bsh file inside extras folder. when i run my command 
java -jar .\lib\bshclient.jar localhost 9000 .\bsh\update.bsh 10 it is telling that file is not found .